# Center image in div with known size. Use either all height or all width. Keep correct ratio. No crop

Tags: html, image, css

I have a square div with a known size.

I want to show an image with an unknown size in it.

I want:

. to use the maximum space in the div to show the image while keeping the size ratio of the image.

. the image to be centered, either horizontally if the image is taller than wider, or vertically if the image is wider than taller.

. I don't want the image to be cropped

. I don't want the image to be stretched and use the whole div

. The image should keep its ratio

I'm fine with either an html img tag or a CSS background image property

Comment: can you provide your code?

Comment: Go research the properties object-fit, background-size

Comment: well, here is some code for example: https://jsfiddle.net/0g2swuet/

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution thanks to @CBroe and his suggestion to use background-size

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center; 
  background-size: contain;
}

.container1 {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/30x50');
}
.container2 {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/50x30');
}
.container3 {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500x300');
}
.container4 {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300x500');
}
```

```html
<div class="container container1">
</div>
<div class="container container2">
</div>
<div class="container container3">
</div>
<div class="container container4">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  position: relative;
}
img {
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/30x50" />
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x30" />
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300" />
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x500" />
</div>
```

Comment: This fix only the last use case

Comment: That is better but on the 2 first use cases, the image should be used the whole height and width respectively

Comment: and I thought "I don't want the image to be stretched and use the whole div"

Comment: Sorry I meant I don't want the image to be stretched both vertically and horizontally in a way that it would lose its original ratio.